# how to remove old data from shoppingcart after drag new one data in shoppingcart

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I want to write some jQuery code which displays only one value at a time when we drag in to it. For example, if I drag `Bank` then it should show only `Bank` after that. If I drag `Rent` it should show only `Rent` and vice versa.

In my jsFiddle there are some code mistakes, please help me to solve them.

```
$("#shoppingCart1 ol").droppable({
    // ....
})
```

[**my jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SC52P/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending dragged items directly. You just need to replace old item with new.

So change your function to this -

```
   var listItem =  $("<li></li>", {
       "text": ui.draggable.text(),
       "data-id": productid

    });
   self.html(listItem);
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/xuBr4/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)  instead of `.appendTo()`

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/SC52P/1/)

```
$(this).html($("<li></li>", {
    "text": ui.draggable.text(),
        "data-id": productid

}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already removing every item from the list that has a class of `placeholder` so just set your new item to have the class of `placeholder`

```
        $("<li></li>", {
           "text": ui.draggable.text(),
           "data-id": productid,
           "class": "placeholder"               
        }).appendTo(this);
```

Now your code will find the item and remove it correctly.

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faaH2/1/)